# "I make plans clear" vs "I make clear plans"

Tags: grammar, adjectives

These sentences are structured differently and I suspect they have different meanings, don't they?

Comment: Yes, they do have different meanings.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you for such a clear answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you "make plans clear", you take some plans that are not clear, and change them, or explain them, so that they are clear.

If you "make clear plans", you start from nothing and make plans that are clear.

The difference is whether you are working with plans that already exist, or making new plans from scratch.

Comment: Usually, if I say I'm making something clear, that doesn't really mean I'm changing it so it becomes clear. It either means I'm ***explaining*** it clearly (so my audience will understand it) OR I'm ***emphasizing*** it (for example, because otherwise my audience might not realize how strongly I feel about the matter).